# ZF2 global config settings

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, config

My goal is to have configuration settings shared and editable within each module in a Zend Framework 2 project. After research, I came to this: http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-2/injecting-configuration-into-a-zf2-controller/ which worked great at first but after my application keeps expanding to more modules and more controllers, I don't appreciate this solution. Precisely, I don't appreciate having to "implement" interface, add SetConfig method and so on. Instead, I'd like to be able to just call on $GLOBALS or similar in my controller and get the parameter of interest.

Say I have a file config.local.php with the following format:

```
    return array(
    'group1' => array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    )

   'group2' => array (
        'subgroup' => array (
             'keyA' => 'valueA',
             'keyB' => 'valueB',
        ),
    )
);
```

Right now, i'm following the tutorial above and after implemeting the ConfigAwareInterface in my controller, I get valueA using

```
$this->config['group2']['subgroup']['keyA']
```

I'm now hoping to just rather call $GLOBALS['group2']['subgroup']['keyA'] without the ConfigAwareInterface intermediate.

I laid the following quick pseudo code to help me achieve that:

```
for every this->config as key => value 
    if $key is not array
        $GLOBALS[$key] => $value
    else 
        for every $value as $k => $v
            $GLOBALS[$key][$k] => $value
```

As ZF2 and php are new to me, I'm not completely sure I can have more than 1 index/nested keys for $GLOBALS but I can tailor my config file to avoid that.

There are probably other logical mistakes above. But just to get the point. Now, is this the best way to go about global configuration or is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can always easily access the configuration via:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('config');
```

What Akrabat did was to provide a shortHand `getConfig()`-

Comment: I should probably edit my question. But the reason I adopted Rob's (Akrabat) approach is because I needed to modify some of the config value from within my application i.e ['group1']['key1'] is initialized to null until I get into Module.php and calculate its result

Comment: Even your comment doesn't modify my answer. There's literally no difference between my and Akrabats approach. The only difference on Akrabats example is, that he only includes a sub-section of the config. But he does nothing but to include `$sl->get('config')`. It will always return the **current state** of the configuration.

Comment: What I currently do is, get config the way you do (through service locator) then modify its value and reset using ->setConfig from the implementation of ConfigAwareInterface. That way, I can have these values for my module as opposed to the ones I capture by calling just ->get('config). So what concerns me is the part where I 'set' these values. Is there a way to do so through the service locator?

Comment: I am a little confused by your setup. When you do `setConfig()` where are your values coming from? Because the config contains all possible values that have been merged by all modules. Modules furthermore are able to overwrite other values. And Values shouldn't be overwritten on runtime from code alone.